# Ошибка: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 27, 48, 1)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Пытаюсь обучить нейросеть на своем датасете. [Пример картинки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2U9l.jpg) (все изображения битовые).

Код создания модели:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1296, activation='relu', input_shape=(27, 48)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Код обучения и создания генератора:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
dirTrain = "D:\\GeneratedI\\train"
train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(dirTrain, target_size=(27, 48), batch_size=20,
                                         class_mode="categorical", color_mode="grayscale")

dirVal = "D:\\GeneratedI\\val"
validation_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(dirVal, target_size=(27, 48), batch_size=20,
                                              class_mode="categorical", color_mode="grayscale")

print("Training the network...")
t_start = time.time()
history = model.fit_generator(train_data,
                              steps_per_epoch=60000 / 20,
                              epochs=10,
                              validation_data=validation_data,
                              validation_steps=6000 / 20)
print(time.time() - t_start)
```

PS Использую tensorflow 1.5 и keras 2.1.6 ввиду отсутствия AVX на моем процессоре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тексту ошибки вы подаете на вход сети 4х-мерный тензор, поэтому попробуйте так:

```
model.add(Dense(1296, activation='relu', input_shape=(27, 48, 1)))
# NOTE:   --------------------------------------->          ^^^
```

PS число образцов / batch_size в размерности `input_shape` не учитывается, поэтому размерность `input_shape` должна быть на единицу меньше размерности входного тензора.